# Not able to select step for the workflow in profiler settings(plugin registration tool)

Tags: plugins

As shown in the below image, I was not able to select the step for the workflow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMXrZ.png)
I want to debug the Custom workflow, for that I have installed the Plugin profiler, On right click on the plugin profiler I came to this page.

in the ideal condition I should be able to select the step of the workflow.